# Intersect or Minus in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below queries,

```
SELECT DISTINCT (U.uid)
FROM users U
    ,friends F
WHERE U.STATUS = '1'
    AND U.uid = F.friend_two
    AND F.friend_one = '1'
    AND F.ROLE = 'fri'
```

And the above query returns 32 rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (U.uid)
FROM users U
    ,friends F
WHERE U.STATUS = '1'
    AND U.uid = F.friend_one
    AND F.friend_two = '1'
    AND F.ROLE = 'fri'
```

And the above query returns 15 rows.

I need to combine and take the intersected results. Intersected rows are 14 rows (means same U.uid in both the tables are 14 rows)

Comment: Both queries are **identical**. Do they really return different number of rows on each run ?

Comment: Nope they are not, `friend_one` and `friend_two` are substituted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT (U.uid) UID
    FROM users U
        ,friends F
    WHERE U.STATUS = '1'
        AND U.uid = F.friend_two
        AND F.friend_one = '1'
        AND F.ROLE = 'fri'
    ) A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT (U.uid) UID
    FROM users U
        ,friends F
    WHERE U.STATUS = '1'
        AND U.uid = F.friend_one
        AND F.friend_two = '1'
        AND F.ROLE = 'fri'
    ) B ON A.UID = B.UID
```

This is basically the intersection on the user id, as you specified, of the two result sets of your two queries.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way to obtain the intersection is simply to join the queries:

```
SELECT uid FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT U.uid
  FROM   users U JOIN friends F ON F.friend_two=U.uid AND F.friend_one = '1'
  WHERE  U.status='1' AND F.role='fri'
) NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT U.uid
  FROM   users U JOIN friends F ON F.friend_one=U.uid AND F.friend_two = '1'
  WHERE  U.status='1' AND F.role='fri'
)
```

However, you could also combine the queries and filter grouped results:

```
SELECT   U.uid
FROM     users U JOIN friends F ON (
           F.friend_one = U.uid AND F.friend_two = '1'
         ) OR (
           F.friend_two = U.uid AND F.friend_one = '1'
         )
WHERE    U.status='1' AND F.role='fri'
GROUP BY U.uid
HAVING   SUM(F.friend_one = U.uid AND F.friend_two = '1')
     AND SUM(F.friend_two = U.uid AND F.friend_one = '1')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite the 2 queries with `EXISTS` instead of the joins, you can first, remove the `DISTINCT` (I assume that `uid` is the primary key of `Users` here) and second, the `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT` (also called `MINUS`) operations are clear:

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT U.uid
FROM users U
WHERE U.status = '1'
  AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM friends F
         WHERE U.uid = F.friend_two
           AND F.friend_one = '1'
           AND F.ROLE = 'fri'
      ) ;
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT U.uid
FROM users U
WHERE U.status = '1'
  AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM friends F
         WHERE U.uid = F.friend_one
           AND F.friend_two = '1'
           AND F.ROLE = 'fri'
      ) ;
```

**Query 3: `INTERSECT`**

```
SELECT U.uid
FROM users U
WHERE U.status = '1'
  AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM friends F
         WHERE U.uid = F.friend_two
           AND F.friend_one = '1'
           AND F.ROLE = 'fri'
      )
  AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM friends F
         WHERE U.uid = F.friend_one
           AND F.friend_two = '1'
           AND F.ROLE = 'fri'
      ) ;
```

**Query 4: `EXCEPT` (`MINUS`)**

```
SELECT U.uid
FROM users U
WHERE U.status = '1'
  AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM friends F
         WHERE U.uid = F.friend_two
           AND F.friend_one = '1'
           AND F.ROLE = 'fri'
      )
  AND NOT EXISTS                       -- notice the NOT here
      ( SELECT *
        FROM friends F
         WHERE U.uid = F.friend_one
           AND F.friend_two = '1'
           AND F.ROLE = 'fri'
      ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another two versions worth to give them a try.
First one is using a semi join, second one joins `friends` table to itself.

```
SELECT distinct(U.uid) 
FROM users U
JOIN friends F  ON U.uid=F.friend_two AND F.friend_one='1'
WHERE U.status='1' AND F.role='fri' 
    AND EXISTS(
      SELECT 1 FROM friends F1
      WHERE U.uid=F1.friend_one 
        AND F1.friend_two='1'
        AND F1.role = 'fri'
    )
;

SELECT distinct(U.uid) 
FROM users U
JOIN friends F  ON U.uid=F.friend_two AND F.friend_one='1'
JOIN friends F1 ON U.uid=F1.friend_one AND F1.friend_two='1'
WHERE U.status='1' AND F.role='fri' AND F1.role = 'fri'
```